# How do I send an array to a child component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to send the array inputArrival and inputBurst to the child component Barchart.js. But whenever I do this only the first element which I enter is being sent and not the other items. Basically what I want is that as the data is being entered into the Entrytable.js it is instantly reflected.
**EntryTable.js**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './tableEdit.css';
import Barchart from './Barchart';

const EntryTable = (props) => {
    const entry = props.numOfEntries;
    const [inputArrival, setInputArrival] = useState(Array(entry).fill(""));
    const [inputBurst, setInputBurst] = useState(Array(entry).fill(""));
  
  
    function changeArrival(index) {     
      return (e) => {
       setInputArrival((values) =>
          values.map((value, i) => (i === index ? e.target.value : value)));};
    }
    function changeBurst(index) {
      return (e) => {  
     setInputBurst((values) =>
          values.map((value, i) => (i === index ? e.target.value : value))         
        );
      };
    }
    const ArrayEntry = Array.from({ length: entry}).map((_, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
          <td >P{i}</td>
          <td >
            <input            
              type="number"
              value={inputArrival[i]}
              onChange={changeArrival(i)}             
            />
            ms
          </td>
          <td >
            <input            
              type="number"
              value={inputBurst[i]}
              onChange={changeBurst(i)}            
            />
            ms
          </td>
        </tr>
    ));
     return (
      <div  c>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Process</th>
              <th>Arrival Time</th>
              <th>Burst Time</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{ArrayEntry}</tbody>
        </table>
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <Barchart selected_val={entry} arrivalArray={inputArrival} ></Barchart>
      </div>
    );
  };
export default EntryTable
```

**Barchart.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
const Barchart=(props)=>{    
  const sel = props.selected_val; 
 var ar1=props.arrivalArray;
 console.log(ar1);
}export default Barchart;
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: First thing, replace the `var` with either `let` or `const`

Comment: Could you provide a minimal and reproducible example please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've tried my best reducing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i got your question, im not sure where is the problem:

- What ive done?

First: As Tasos said converted all the variables to `let`;

Second: Assigned a value of 5 for the `const entry`
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AftDx.png)

Third: Added one more prop for the other array of data you want, and pass it to the child component `Barchart.js`;
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElRMN.png)

And this is the result:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyalq.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much. Doing all this and assinging const entry=5. Seems to do the job but whenever I am using props to get the value it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, so my suggestion is to simply `console.log(props)` in your parent element and whit that you will be able to debug it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ran your code and even though you have some improvements to add to it, other than this it seems to work.

[image]

The only difference is returning something in `Barchart.js`. Maybe try to return null in `Barchart.js`, it might throw a silent error.

I recommend using a linter also for code styling.

Comment: Since the maximum value that my array ```inputArrival``` and ```inputBurst``` can accomodate is 8. 
    ``` const [inputArrival, setInputArrival] = useState(Array(8).fill(""));
    const [inputBurst, setInputBurst] = useState(Array(8).fill("")); 
    ```
Filling this with with the value of the props was causing an issue but now its fixed